# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference ошибка

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня случилась проблема `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`. Не могу понять причину. В манифесте активити объявлена, в xml есть привязка, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема, спасибо!

OpenDate:

```
public class OpenDate extends AppCompatActivity {
Boolean noti;

private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
private ActivityOpenDateBinding binding;
public static final int[] NOTIF_DATE = new int[]{6,14,28};
Note n;
NoteDao nd;

TextView[] tv1;
TextView[] tv3;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv4;
TextView tv5;

int[] d1;
int[] d3;
int d2;
int d4;
int d5;
String date0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final int bd_id =  intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
    nd = App.getInstance().getNd();

    n = nd.getById(bd_id);

    final TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.tv_name0);
    final TextView por = findViewById(R.id.tv_por);
    final TextView color = findViewById(R.id.tv_color);
    final TextView date = findViewById(R.id.date0);

    tv_name.setText(n.getName());
    por.setText(n.getPoroda());
    color.setText(n.getColor());
    date0 =n.getDate();
    date.setText(date0);

     tv1 = new TextView[]{
            findViewById(R.id.date1),
            findViewById(R.id.date2),
            findViewById(R.id.date3),
            findViewById(R.id.date4),
            findViewById(R.id.date5),
            findViewById(R.id.date6),
            findViewById(R.id.date7),
            findViewById(R.id.date8),
            findViewById(R.id.date9),
            findViewById(R.id.date11)
    };
     tv3 = new TextView[]{
            findViewById(R.id.date14),
            findViewById(R.id.date15),
            findViewById(R.id.date16),
    };
     tv2 = findViewById(R.id.date12);
     tv4 = findViewById(R.id.date10);
     tv5 = findViewById(R.id.date13);


    //
     d1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11};
     d3 = new int[]{22,25,28}; //+2
     d2 = 15; //+1
     d4 = 10; //+3
     d5 = 17; //+4



    CheckBox notif = findViewById(R.id.cb_notif);

    noti = n.notif;
    if (noti) {
        notif.setActivated(true);
    }
    //Cтатус уведомлений
    notif.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        noti=!noti;
        n.notif = noti;
        nd.ins(n);

        if(noti){
            Toast.makeText(OpenDate.this, "Вам придут уведомления в даты, отмеченные жирным шрифтом.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

});

    binding = ActivityOpenDateBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    ImageButton del = findViewById(R.id.ib_del);
    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(OpenDate.this);
            dlg.setMessage("Вы уверены, что хотите удалить запись?")
                    .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Удалить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dele();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
            dlg.show();
        }
    });

}

private void dele() {
    nd.del(n);
    Toast.makeText(OpenDate.this, "Запись успешно удалена.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = new Intent(OpenDate.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}


protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(OpenDate.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void fill_tv(){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date0, formatter);
    for (int i=0; i<d1.length;i++){
        LocalDate incrementedDate = localDate.plusDays(d1[i]);
        tv1[i].setText(incrementedDate.format(formatter));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<d3.length;i++){
        LocalDate iDate = localDate.plusDays(d3[i]);
        LocalDate iDatee = localDate.plusDays(d3[i]+2);
        tv3[i].setText(iDate.format(formatter)+" - "+iDatee.format(formatter));
    }

    LocalDate iDate = localDate.plusDays(d4);
    LocalDate iDatee = localDate.plusDays(d4+3);
    tv4.setText(iDate.format(formatter)+" - "+iDatee.format(formatter));

    iDate = localDate.plusDays(d5);
    iDatee = localDate.plusDays(d5+3);
    tv5.setText(iDate.format(formatter)+" - "+iDatee.format(formatter));

    iDate = localDate.plusDays(d2);
    iDatee = localDate.plusDays(d2+1);
    tv2.setText(iDate.format(formatter)+" - "+iDatee.format(formatter));
}
}
```

activity_open_date:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".OpenDate">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Улей:"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Порода пчел:"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_por"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="____________________"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="____________________"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_por" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Цвет матки:"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="_____________________________"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_notif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Уведомления"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="485dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_color">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textV3iew12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Дата закладки матки:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textVi3ew9"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Стадии развития матки"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/te3xtView9"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Яйцо"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t3extView12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Стоячее:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textVie3w12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Наклонное:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView123"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Лежачее:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView39"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Личинка"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t3extVie3w12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Однодневная:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView312"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Двухдневная:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textVi3ew12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Трехдневная (контроль):"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text3View12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Четырехдневная:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex3tView12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Пятидневная:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView132"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Печатка:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textVie3w9"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Куколка"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textV33iew12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Запечатка:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textVi33ew12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Отбор:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Матка"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tex33tView12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Выход матки:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>



            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textV333iew12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Дозревание матки:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/te33xtView12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Облет матки:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textVi333ew12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Осеменение матки:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Контроль кладки яиц:"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="----"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_del"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cb_notif"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Ошибка то в какой строке

Answer (score 0):

Вы ищите вьюхи в разметке до того, как эту разметку загружаете. Перенесите строки

```
binding = ActivityOpenDateBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

до первых вызовов `findViewById`